# Notepad ++ how to search for specific spaces?

Tags: notepad++

I have a text in a Notepad++ that has specific amount of spaces.

```
  "revision": ,
  "checking": {
    "startcount": {
      "dateCreated": "20230101",
      "definitions": {
        "Gamesplayed": {
          "community": false,
```

I would like to select all the lines that have exactly 12 spaces. In this case, this would be:

```
Gamesplayed
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Regex search `\s{12}(.*)`

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm not too familiar, but where can I put this?

Comment: There should be a "search mode" option when you press CTRL + F to search. Select regex there and paste the above. Or use this one to get just `GamesPlayed` `\s{12}"(\w+)":\s{`

Comment: Might say "Regular expression" instead of "regex"

Comment: Thank you! I found it! But it also gives me all the other lines that have greater than 12 spaces. Is there a way to only include the 12 spaces?

Comment: I've added an answer which also addresses the 12 spaces issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression to search for the lines that have exactly 12 spaces

```
^\s{12}"(\w+)":\s{
```

[Example on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Lsj0On/1)

**Explanation:**

- `^` - Denotes the start of the line
- `\s` - Matches whitespace character
- `{12}` - Matches the previous token exactly 12 times
- `"` - Literal quote
- `(\w+)` - Capture group capturing any word
- `"` - Literal quote
- `:` - Literal colon
- `\s` - Matches on space
- `{` - Literal curly left brace

You could also shorten the regex using

```
^\s{12}(.*)
```

Where `(.*)` will just capture everything

Comment: thank you so much! But when I try ^\s{12}(.*), it gives me all the lines that have greater than 12 spaces, is there a way to have only the lines that have exactly 12 spaces?

Comment: Oh I missed the first line! Thank you so much, this worked!! :) And thank you for all the explanations and definitions as well, very helpful!